# Retain zoom level on new tab for page inside same website

Tags: firefox, zoom

When I have set the zoom-level at for example 120% for a website (e.g. StackOverflow) and I open a link to another page of that website (e.g.: a question on StackOverflow) in a new tab, the zoom-level is reset too 100%. However, when I open that page in the same tab the zoom-level stays at 120%.

I updated Firefox today and have also been changing stuff in `about:config` (based on [this guide](https://github.com/gunnersson/my_Mozilla_settings/blob/master/Firefox/user.js.md))

Untill this morning opening a page of the same website preserved the zoom-level.

Some additional details:

- Browserversion: Firefox 59.01
- OS: macOS 10.12.6

I have tried setting back many (if not all) of the changes in `about:config`. In addition to that I also tried to change `browser.zoom.siteSpecific` and `zoom.minPercent`. All without succes so far.

Any ideas which settings in `about:config` I have to change?

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nosquint-plus - Manage site-specific zoom levels and color settings

Comment: @DavidPostill I know about the NoSquint addon, but I would preferably solve it without an addon.

Comment: There is no such capability built into Firefox. An add-on is the only method there is of doing this: Either using one already made, or making one yourself.

Comment: @music2myear Yes, there is. I removed Firefox and did a clean install after that. Now I have the desired behavior again.

Comment: Write up that solution and post it as the answer, then mark the answer as correct. This will help others with the same problem who find this question.

Comment: @music2myear thx & done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to remove Firefox and do a clean install after that.